# Using jest.mock for Angular Pipes, Directives and Components

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jestjs

I am starting to use Jest to unit test Angular components.
I am trying to get an automatic mock of the Angular Translate pipe by beginning the unit test with:

```
import { TranslatePipe, TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';

jest.mock('@ngx-translate/core');
```

Expecting to be able to now inject this mocked pipe into the component using something like this:

```
 ...
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [..., TranslatePipe],
      ...
     });
```

The tests, however, crash with reason being:

```
Unexpected value 'TranslatePipe' declared by the module 'DynamicTestModule'. Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation.
```

Am I missing the point of jest.mock()? Is it used for something other than what I'm trying to do?
Is it possible to make jest apply the @Pipe decorator?